# How to find amino acid sequence of a given protein

Tags: proteins, sequence-analysis

Is there a way to look up the amino acid sequence of a given protein? For example, what amino acids are used to produce Amylase? I spent hours googling but to no avail. If that's impossible, how can I find the sequence of A, C, G, U of the mRNA that instructs the ribosome to produce Amylase?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what protein you are looking for. Which amylase? From which species? You can find anything you want on sites like https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ or https://ensembl.org among others. Depending on the species of interest, you can also find more focused resources, so tell us what you're after (you mention both protein and mRNA, both are possible, but which one do you want?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you go and search in a database. NCBI and Uniprot (specialized on proteins) are ways to go here.

These two offer tons of other related information, links to other databases, advanced functionalities like similarity search based on sequence (e.g. blastp). etc.

To narrow your search, you would need to specify which species you are interested. Here a quick result for amylase in humans, using [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/?term=Amylase+homo+sapiens) and [Uniprot](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/P0DTE8/entry). The nucleotide sequence is [linked](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/M28443.1) in both cases.

Comment: I have no knowledge of biology, thus I had no idea a same protein name (Amylase in this case) will have a different structure for each species (thus vague OP). This question arose from a Python programming homework. Do you happen to know what these letters `mkfflllfti gfcwaqyspn tqqgrtsivh...` mean from the `origin` of this link https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/AAA51724.1?